# How to fetch the date from epoch in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a column which has the time stamp stored in epoch. I need to fetch the date from the epoch time stamp. For instance for epoch = 1552942715, I need to fetch the date as 1552867200. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried, and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test (epoch text NULL);
```

Create table sample where the column is text datatype.

```
select (epoch::int)::TIMESTAMPTZ from test;
```

If the column is of type int or any other number then just cast it to timestampz